# Disable xsave in glibc's ld.so

Tags: assembly, linker, gdb, x86-64, glibc

I would like to use gdb's recording, but because glibc's ld.so uses xsave instructions, I get the error "Process record does not support instruction 0xfae64 at address 0x7ffff7fe883c."

I was able to fix a similar error with binary patching thanks to a [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42451492/disable-avx-optimized-functions-in-glibc-ld-hwcap-mask-etc-ld-so-nohwcap-for). Compiling glibc with debug symbols failed after running for half an hour, so I'd be glad if there's a quicker solution. I got a compiled version from [here](https://pkgbuild.com/~eschwartz/repo/x86_64/), but it looks like there are no earlier versions offered (i.e. I'm using glibc 2.28.r502.g065957a3704-1 now and gdb 8.2.1). How can I make gdb recording work?

Comment: Try using a newer gdb version.

Comment: @fuz 8.2.1 is the latest gdb release as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Two possible solutions I found: (a) set `LD_BIND_NOW=1` before running the program or (b) do a static link.  Both are recommended workarounds according to [this thread](https://sourceware.org/ml/gdb/2016-08/msg00025.html).

Comment: @fuz Oh cool, these workarounds both work, want to write it up as a solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the x86 emulator built into gdb doesn't understand many newer instructions. The only fix for this is waiting for a new version with the relevant instructions patched in.  In the meanwhile, [this thread](https://sourceware.org/ml/gdb/2016-08/msg00025.html) suggests a number of workarounds:

- load the binary with the environment variable `LD_BIND_NOW` set to `1` to avoid triggering `xsave` in the dynamic linker
- alternatively, link the binary you want to debug statically
- alternatively, link with `-z now` e.g. by passing `-Wl,-z,now` to the C compiler

Comment: Static linking is not required, `-Wl,-z,now` for the main program and all libraries will suffice.

Comment: Could you explain why that works? Is it that the default function call resolution when symbols are first referenced uses xsave when doing a context switch between the binary and the dynamic linker, but if symbols are resolved at startup, then context will never be switched between binary and dynamic linker?

Comment: @rubystallion Sorry, no idea.

Comment: @rubystallion: Florian's deleted answer mentions that lazy dynamic linking uses `xsave` in lazy dynamic linking trampolines.  I think this might be to avoid SSE/AVX transition stalls, either in the dynamic-linker code, or worse when returning to the main program.  It's possible to create a situation where SSE instructions have false dependencies forever: [Why is this SSE code 6 times slower without VZEROUPPER on Skylake?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41303780).  Although I'm not sure why they can't just use `vzeroupper`, because the SysV ABI says a function call clobbers the vector regs.